# Spotlight: Unknown indexing state

Tags: bootcamp, high-sierra, spotlight

I'm using a late-2016 MacBook Pro with Touch Bar running macOS 10.13.3. Today, I've been trying to install a Bootcamp partition. Before partitioning and installing Windows, Spotlight worked.

However, after the Bootcamp installation was successful, Spotlight has been broken, as is Google Drive, which now refuses to accept the location of the Google Drive folder. Disk Utility refuses to load any disks as well as the Startup Disk pane in System Preferences, which says there are no startup disks at all.

When it comes to Spotlight, I'm trying to get it to reindex. However, it gives me this:

```
$ sudo mdutil -i off /
/:
Error: unable to perform operation.  (-400)
    Error: unknown indexing state.
```

The output is the same when running `sudo mdutil -E /`.